# ConvertFrom-String missing properties

Tags: powershell, validation

I'm new to ConvertFrom-String and need to be able to make the following work. It's just a basic sample, but it's what I need.

I have the following data that needs to be parsed to a CSV.

```
FirstName: John
LastName: Doe
Email: jdoe@hotmail.com
Tel: 666555444

FirstName: Robert
LastName: Smith
url: www.smith.com
```

Both sets of data have 'FirstName' and 'LastName' but one set has email and tel. and the other lacks the latter but has url. After parsing to CSV using ConvertFrom-String i should be getting:

```
 FirstName LastName Email            Tel       url
 Johhn     Doe      jdoe@hotmail.com 666555444
 Robert    Smith                               www.smith
```

But what I'm getting instead is:

```
 FirstName LastName Email            Tel       
 Johhn     Doe      jdoe@hotmail.com 666555444
 Robert    Smith    www.smith.com    www.smith.com
```

The template i'm using:

```
$template=@'

FirstName: {FirstNameNombre*:John}
LastName: {LastName:Doe}
Email: {Email:jdoe@hotmail.com}
Tel: {Tel:666555444}

FirstName: {Nombre*:Robert}
LastName: {Apellidos:Smith}
url: {url:www.smith.com}

'@

$listContacts = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Conversor_ABK2CVS\Pbas.txt"
$listContacts | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template
```

I have Googled and searched in forums but the closest I found to what might fix this is in:

https://foxdeploy.com/2015/01/13/walkthrough-part-two-advanced-parsing-with-convertfrom-string/

where it mentions the use of ? and ! for indicating the parser that a variable is optional  or not wanted but it is not clear to me how to use them. I've tried {url?:} in the first template set but I keep getting errors when running the script.

Any ideas on how to make this work? This is just a basic sample but the idea is to use what i learn here to facilitate the migration of > 300 contacts in several address books of 6 MFPs (Canon) to a new ones (Sharp). Canon old models do not provide export to CSV but to a format similar to the sample (there being email and folder addresses).

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

--
Jorge

Comment: [`ConvertFrom-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-string) provides separator-based parsing as well as heuristics-based parsing based on templates containing example values. The separator-based parsing applies automatic type conversions you cannot control, and the template language is poorly documented, with the exact behavior hard to predict - it's best to avoid this cmdlet altogether. Also note that it is no longer available in _PowerShell (Core)_ (v6+).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a huge fan of `ConvertFrom-String` even though many say it's problematic. It has been removed from newer versions of powershell as well. All that aside, I don't think it's the right tool for this job. You need relatively consistent data. I would like to offer an alternative solution. Your example shows the data split by an empty line. If that is not the case, let me know and I can adjust the answer.

**Sample data**

```
$text = @'
FirstName: John
LastName: Doe
Email: jdoe@hotmail.com
Tel: 6665554444

FirstName: Robert
LastName: Smith
url: www.smith.com
'@
```

First we will split the sections by the empty line. We will use two empty lines based on the calling systems `[Environment]::newline`. Then for each section we will capture the desired data based on the regex match using a switch statement. We need to clear the variables to ensure nothing gets carried over from previous sections. Finally any matches get populated in the pscustomobject creation.

```
$nl = [environment]::NewLine

$data = $text -split "$nl$nl"| foreach {
    Remove-Variable first,last,email,tel,url -ErrorAction Ignore

    switch -Regex ($_){
        'FirstName: (.+)' {$first = $matches.1}
        'LastName: (.+)' {$last = $matches.1}
        'Email: (.+)' {$email = $matches.1}
        'Tel: (.+)' {$tel = $matches.1}
        'URL: (.+)' {$url = $matches.1}
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        FirstName = $first
        LastName  = $last
        Email     = $email
        Tel       = $tel
        URL       = $url
    }
}
```

**Contents of `$data`**

```
FirstName : John
LastName  : Doe
Email     : jdoe@hotmail.com
Tel       : 666555444
URL       : 

FirstName : Robert
LastName  : Smith
Email     : 
Tel       : 
URL       : www.smith.com
```

**`$data` output as table**

```
$data | Format-Table

FirstName LastName Email             Tel       URL          
--------- -------- -----             ---       ---          
John...   Doe...   jdoe@hotmail.c... 666555444              
Robert... Smith...                             www.smith.com
```

All that's left is to export to CSV

```
$data | Export-Csv -Path some\path\to.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

**Edit**

If reading from a file, it's important that it's all one string so do

```
$mydata = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Conversor_ABK2CVS\sample2.txt" -Raw
```